# Check if GPS is moving or is stopped

Tags: algorithm, gps

I'm trying to record every place a GPS stopped for at least X minutes, but I'm having
 some problems identifying it. What I did until now is running through every point checking if the speed is less than Y km/h from the last point, But this is the heavy (and dumb) way and I believe (altough I didn't find anything) that there must be a better way. I would like to know if there is a existing algorithm that does that or if you guys can give some guidance about where to go.

I don't have any sensor access, only the GPS position each 6 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to check the speed. All you need to do is check the position. Assuming you have an array of positions, you can do something like:

```
int secondsStopped = 0;
Position stoppedPos = positions[0];

for (int i = 1; i < positions.Length; ++i)
{

    if (positions[i] == stoppedPos)
    {
        secondsStopped += 6;
    }
    else
    {
        // it moved.
        if (secondsStopped >= TARGET_TIME)
        {
            output("Stopped at " + stoppedPos + " for " + secondsStopped + " seconds.");
            stoppedPos = positions[i];
            secondsStopped = 0;
        }
    }
}
// check last period
if (secondsStopped >= TARGET_TIME)
{
    output("Stopped at " + stoppedPos + " for " + secondsStopped + " seconds.");
}
```

Because GPS often won't give you the exact same position each period, even when the thing is perfectly still, you probably need to change that equality check to something like:

```
if (ComputeDistance(positions[i], stoppedPos) <= SOME_SMALL_VALUE)
```

I don't know what `SOME_SMALL_VALUE` should be. You'll have to experiment to find out what seems reasonable.

You'll also have to find a distance formula. Shouldn't be too hard. And because the GPS isn't going to move very far in 6 seconds, you can pretend that the world is flat (makes distance calculation very easy). I don't know what your GPS data looks like, but assuming that you're given latitude and longitude, you can check out my article [Computing Track Information in GPS](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=513) for a simple distance calculation.

Comment: The problem is this "ComputeDistance" comparing with the Last Position, this last position can be very far from the first, imagining a 30 minutes verification its 180 points. The GPS could move really slow for instance. Then, for instance if the 180th point invalidate all the rest but the 181th point can validate if the first point is ignored. It's really heavy. I don't know if I was clear.